# PHP Autologout function not working if browser is closed

Tags: php

I am aware that similar questions have been asked, but none seem to have a good solution. I have a auto logout function ( see below).

However if the tab/browser is closed, the session is never destroyed, and more importantly the DB table `tblTimeLog` is not updated.

What I want to do is for the "timer to keep running" even tho the browser or tab is closed. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Auto logout function:

```
<?
session_start();

// set timeout period in seconds
$idleTime = 2400;
header("refresh: 2400");

// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $idleTime) { 
        $db->Execute("UPDATE tblTimeLog SET LogoutTime = NOW() WHERE sid ='".session_id()."'".$row['konsulentid'].'');
        session_destroy(); 
        header("Location: login.php?loggut");
        exit(); 
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time(); 
?>
```

Comment: you can catch event of tab close... & do what you want ... Also if you cant then update your DB next time when he come after expiration time

Comment: @chhameed thanks for answer, this requires javascript am i correct? also updating the DB the next time is not an option. As we need the DB to be up-to-date at all times, regardless if the user returns or not

Comment: yes javascript, but if you dont want to use javascript then cron-job is the best solution for this. which run after a specific time & update the table accordingly

Comment: **Do not** catch the tab close event, or implement any other JavaScript solution for that matter. Anything client-side can be circumvented and abused. This needs to be a server-side solution.

Comment: @michael Thanks for your concern, but it is a closed solution for a small company, where we want this to log our hours rather than having to do it manually, there is close to zero risk that anyone will abuse this at all. edit: i am interested in seeing the "correct" way to do it tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the auto-logout only takes effect upon a request to your server.

You want your system to log users out regardless of whether they're still making requests *or not*.

One simple solution would be to set up [a cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a PHP script every minute or so. Have the script loop through all users, and log them out if necessary. This would require you to additionally store the last time they made a request in the database, as that's currently stored in a session that you would not have access to in a different script.

Alternatively, on a successful (logged in) request, you could schedule a script to log the user out. On each subsequent request, cancel that scheduled execution and schedule another.

Which solution you choose will depend on your exact system. Weigh up the pros and cons of each. The first might not be suitable, for example, because it will run all the time regardless of whether anyone is actually logged in.

Comment: Great, i will have to do some reading to figure out how to set up a cron job! thanks for the suggestion tho. Im learning new things every day still as im quite new to php! i will flag your answer as solution once i get it to work!

Comment: ok so i'm still at it, and haven't solved my problem yet. @Michael you wrote: "Alternatively, on a successful (logged in) request, you could schedule a script to log the user out. On each subsequent request, cancel that scheduled execution and schedule another." 
any suggestion on how i should go about to achieve this? i did try with  window.onbeforeunload, however this also triggers the onbeforeunload whenever i navigate to sub-pages.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload`? It sounds like you're attempting a client-side solution. I will reiterate: do not do that. Why did you decide a cron job is not appropriate? To schedule a job on linux, use `at`. To cancel that job, use `at -r`.

Comment: for a cron job i have to access the server to schedule it through linux, the problem is that i do not have access to that. so if it is not achieveable to set up a cron job with php/html/javascript etc. that i upload to the server, a cron job is not my solution. 
Again the "security" issues from doing it client side, is not a real problem in my environment, and so i think this is the way to go. i dont know how achievable this is, but the ideal solution to me would be to somehow run the $db update to tblTimeLog whenever the tab/browser is closed.

Comment: If you have access to PHP, you absolutely have access to the linux server - what do you think PHP is running on? Whether you have appropriate permissions is another thing.

Comment: yeah. ofcourse... that doesn't really help me out tho. But i won't waste any more of your time, thanks for trying. i'll keep fiddling with it until i can make it work

Answer (score 0):

IMO a reasonable solution is to have a cron job that periodically goes through all sessions in tblTimeLog table and updates the table's LogoutTime if timeout occured. Next time, if client with session id that got logged out by the cron script connects again, you destroy the session cookie. This would only require storing in the DB session expiration time.